# Using routerLink in a string in angular2 not working

Tags: angular2-routing

```
var str = '<a routerLink="/SomeLink">Some Link</a>
```

I am trying to insert few links through Javascript where I have routerLink as path specified. But its not working, its rendering as it is. Please suggest how to use a routerLink inside a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = '<a routerLink="/SomeLink" href="#/SomeLink">Some Link</a>
```

I added href, its working fine. Thank you All.

Answer (score 0):

> its rendering as it is

Are you trying add this element with `document.getElementBy...().innerHtml = str`?

if so, I think this is going under the "not in angular2 spirit" title...

I'm suggesting you to read a bit more about `creating dynamic elements in angular 2+`.

Comment: Actually I have assigned this whole string as a value to an Object's key. Iam using object.key to show the data/passing to the data table plugin.

Comment: care to share some code? the html part would be helpful I think

Comment: `var str = '<a routerLink="/SomeLink" href="#/SomeLink">Some Link</a>`
I just added href & it worked fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution but I think the `routerLink` here is unnecessary, or not doing what you really want. for my  understanding, the `routerLink` is used in angular2 for routing in your app, while the `href` is more general.